# 301 redirects after changing permalinks

Tags: permalinks, redirect, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I've recently changed my permalink structure from `/%category%/%post_id%/` to `/%category%/%postname%/`.

I've also switched from Yoast to The SEO Framework plugin. Prior to making that switch, I deleted all redirects from Yoast settings; and after, I've updated the sitemap settings on Google Webmaster tools to point to the new sitemap file, and deleted the old one (Yoast).

After 2 weeks, I keep receiving a lot of 301 hits from google search. Strange thing, many of those hits lead to one specific post on my page.

Here is one example:

```
curl -I https://famagusta.news/local/paralimni/201400/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 01 May 2019 22:21:37 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=99215018a76ae1b09b0411b37586eb87;     path=/
Location: https://famagusta.news/local/paralimni/paralimni-15-chronia-apo-ta-mavra-christougenna-tou-2002-vinteo/201400/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish: 1365431
Age: 0
X-Cache: MISS
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: WordPress appear to be working correctly by redirecting this request. Unless this url still exists in the sitemap, the problem is with the pages Google has in its index and not WordPress.

Comment: Hello. The post is not in the new index submitted. How do i inform google? Should i add a custom 301? Because this happens pretty much with all the google results for posts prior to changing permalinks and sitemap

Comment: You need to re-index you page, request the crawler again within the search-console.